# how to write a function to filter rows based on a list values one by one and make analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a list contains more than 10 values and I have a full dataframe. I'd like to filter each value from the list to a subdataframe and do some analysis on each of them. How can I write a function so I don't need to copy paste and change value so many times.

eg.

```
list = ['A','B','C'] 
df1 = df[df['column1']=='A']
df2 = df[df['column1']=='B']
df3 = df[df['column1']=='C']
```

for each subdataframe ,I will do a groupby and value count

```
df1.groupby(['column2']).size()
df2.groupby(['column2']).size()
df3.groupby(['column2']).size()
```

Comment: Do you want 3 python variables? df1, df2, df3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First many DataFrames is here not necessary.

You can filter only necessary values for `column1` and pass both columns to `groupby`:

```
L = ['A','B','C']

s = df1[df1['column1'].isin(L)].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).size()
```

Last select by values of list:

```
s.loc['A']
s.loc['B']
s.loc['C']
```

If want function:

```
def f(df, x):
    return df[df['column1'].eq(L)].groupby(['column2']).size()


print (f(df1, 'A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()` to create variables dynamically (it's not really a good practice but it works well):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': list('ABC') * 3, 'column2': list('IKJIJKLNK')})
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for idx, elmt in enumerate(lst, 1):
    locals()[f"df{idx}"] = df[df['column1'] == elmt]
```

```
>>> df3
  column1 column2
2       C       J
5       C       K
8       C       K

>>> df3.value_counts('column2')
  column1  column2
column2
K    2
J    1
dtype: int64

>>> df
  column1 column2
0       A       I
1       B       K
2       C       J
3       A       I
4       B       J
5       C       K
6       A       L
7       B       N
8       C       K
```